# How to export two schemas to the same file in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know how to have two different database schemas in the same file.  I have used the scripting tool in SSMS but it only seems to be one at a time. Preferably using the SSMS scripting tool to do this but if that isn't possible then I will take what I can get

Comment: The Generate Scripts feature works fine for me, and puts 2 schemas from the same database in the script without issue.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for that comment but I would like to do two different databases into one file

Comment: SSMS's scripting is built on SMO, and can be used directly in PowerShell or any .NET language: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/scripting?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I took David Browne's advice and used powershell and it worked very well thank you